# Is there a better name for what I'm calling a Vanity Lookup?

Tags: related-list, lookup

Here is an example from a 3rd party managed package of what I am currently calling a "Vanity Lookup" because it is totally redundant from an OOD/ERD perspective and I assume it is only for convenience:

Defining: `QuoteLine->QuoteLineGroup->Quote`

Vanity: `QuoteLine->Quote`

My example:

Defining: `LicenseKey->Asset->Account`

Vanity: `LicenseKey->Account`

My License Key custom object has a lookup to Asset. Simple right. Assets belong to Accounts though so there is an implied relationship from LicenseKey->Asset->Account. Fine. I know how to take advantage of that through SOQL queries and relationship report types. From an OOD or ERD perspective I'm done. But there is so much **out-of-the-box goodness** if I have a lookup from LicenseKey->Account too. I'm calling this a "vanity lookup" because it is a truly unnecessary and redundant relationship but it **"looks better" when I get that free related list** on my Accounts page (itemizing all of the License Keys for an Account) or my coworkers get to do easy Account->LicenseKey reporting without having to jump through the extra relationship.

Ultimately, I'm interested in the **best practices** for this technique. Is it discouraged? Is it as simple as marking the Vanity Lookup read-only and keeping it in sync with workflow? In an effort to keep my question specific I'll settle for the proper name so I can go search for the best practices myself... but hey, if you want to point me to a good article or share the best practices from your experience I'm all ears.

Comment: Best practice finding #1: use a trigger to keep the vanity/implied lookup in sync with the defining relationship. Workflow doesn't allow you to change custom lookup fields from field updates. The [idea to allow this](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrGdAAK) has been around for a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using it purely for on-screen information it's redundant and could be replaced with a formula field easily enough.

However I'd argue that in some situations this lookup would likely exist to benefit a developer, there could be circumstances where even though there is a connection between object A & B via some route, a direct lookup field could save a lot of headaches. In this scenario I'd just refer to it as a lookup.

Comment: It's mostly the automatic related list I want, which I can't get with just a formula. I'll take your explanation as a vote for this being an accepted practice anyways. Maybe this is so simple it doesn't need a name or a best practice guide. Where relationship #1 dictates relationship #2, keep #2 in sync with workflow or a trigger and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Transitive Lookup because A->B and B->C implies/requires A->C.

Comment: Just a pedantic point, but since SFDC allows multiple lookups between object types, if you have multiple lookups of B->C (e.g. B->C1 and B->C2), you don't know from looking at the "A" screen, holding lookup B and vanity lookup C, which B->C relationship is being navigated. That said, this sort of thing is done all the time in the implementations I've seen and I call them something like "implied lookup" or "automated lookup".

Answer (score 0):

New idea for when you're really after just the UI goodness and don't need it for reporting... Don't add the vanity/implied/automated lookup to the data model at all. Instead, in the UI, build and expose a lightning component that queries with the main relationship and shows related information. Saves on limits too. We're having success with this approach.